# What is the proper way for me to handle network access for a device

Tags: c#, oop, tcp, blazor-server-side, modbus

I am currently working on a blazor server project which will display information from modbus tcp/ip devices. I have a class called "DeviceModel" which models a Modbus device. A simplified example is shown below.

```
public string DeviceName {get;set;}
public string IpAddress {get;set;}
public string Port {get;set;}
public int[] Registers {get;set;}
public string Alarm1 {get;set;}
```

The device model class also contains methods to parse information from the Registers. For example the snippet below will check the value at a certain index in the Registers array. Based on that value it will set the Alarm1 property to ON or OFF.

```
public void CheckAlarm1(){
int status = Registers[4];
Alarm1 = status == 1 ? "ON" : "OFF";

}
```

I have another class called "NetworkAccess" which handles the TCP/IP connection to a device. A simplified example is shown below

```
// ModbusClient is a package which handles the reading/writing to TCP/IP Modbus 
private ModbusClient _client;
public string IPAddress {get;set;}
public string Port {get;set;}
public DeviceModel Device {get;set;}

public NetworkAccess(DeviceModel dev){
      IPAddress = dev.IPAddress;
      Port = dev.Port;
      _client = new ModbusClient(IPAddress,Port);
      _client.Connect();
}
```

The NetworkAccess class handles reading and writing data to/from the device on the network. An example method which would write data to a single register on the Modbus device is below.

```
public void WriteSingleRegister(int address,int dataToAdd){
     _client.WriteSingleRegister(address,dataToAdd);
}
```

Within my Razor Component for the webpage, within the OnInitialized() method I get a List containing DeviceModels from a database which fills in information such as IPAddress,Port, and Name for each device. To read information to the device, I have another method "GetData()" shown below

```
public async void GetData(){
     foreach(var device in Devices){
          NetworkAccess network = new NetworkAccess(dev);
          var dataUpdate = await network.ReadRegistersAsync(0,20);
          dev.Registers= dataUpdate;
     }
}
```

The way I currently have this setup works fine. In order to write to a device I would do something like this in my Razor Component

```
NetworkAccess network = new NetworkAccess(dev);
network.WriteRegistersAsync(0,new int[] {0,0,0,...}};
```

Where I am having trouble is I am not sure the of the correct (or best) way to handle my situation. In my head it makes more sense to me if I had methods within my DeviceModel class for specific operations such as "ResetAlarm1" or "ClearRegisters". That way I could do

```
dev.ResetAlarm1();
```

rather than doing this in my razor component below

```
NetworkAccess net = new NetworkAccess(dev)
dev.WriteRegister(6,0); // where 6 is the register to write to and 0 is value to write
```

I guess my question is should I add "NetworkAccess" to the device model and handle creating the connection and reading/writing to the device within that? Or does it make more sense to keep NetworkAccess and DeviceModel seperate?

I hope this post makes sense. This is more a question about design than it is about fixing a problem. While my current solution is working fine, I want to better understand if this is the correct approach or if I am way off.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or does it make more sense to keep NetworkAccess and DeviceModel separate?

[As single responsibility principle of SOLID says:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)

> The single-responsibility principle (SRP) is a computer-programming
> principle that states that every module, class or function in a
> computer program should have responsibility over a single part of that
> program's functionality, and it should encapsulate that part. All of
> that module, class or function's services should be narrowly aligned
> with that responsibility.

Read more about [single responsibility principle of SOLID](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/clarify-the-single-responsibility-principle) here.

So making separate method `dev.ResetAlarm1()` in `Device` class is more preferable for me.

It is hard to say whether my refactoring code is appropriate to you, but I tried to do my best:

```
public class Device
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string IpAddress { get; set; }

    public string Port { get; set; }

    public int[] Registers { get; set; }

    public string[] Alarms { get; set; }


    public void CheckAlarm(int registerIndex)
    {
        int status = Registers[registerIndex];
        Alarms[registerIndex] = status == 1 ? "ON" : "OFF";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That clears things up for me

Comment: @hoefsdavid9701  I am glad that it helped to you